# How to express "helluva" or "extremely" in British English?

Tags: word-choice, british-english

**How to express "helluva" or "extremely" in a very British way?**

I know "jolly" for "very", but I'm searching for a word meaning "extremely" (so quite stronger), especially to use in a situation of heavy emotions.

I also know "f...ing", but it's too universal (and perhaps too vulgar as well).

Examples:

- This is extremely stupid!
- Is he an extreme idiot or what?
- [optional] I damn hate him!
- [optional] This film was extremely beautiful!

Comment: Probably the most "British" way to say "This is extremely stupid" is "This isn't the cleverest thing in the world"  (Joke)...   So are you looking for a "stereotype" of British or actual British?  And which British?  Scottish? Cockney, West Country, Home Counties? Welsh? Liverpool?  North Yorks?.......

Comment: "Jolly" for example, is "stereotypical".  Actual British people don't say "Jolly" to mean very in most contexts.  "Jolly good" might be used sometimes but "That was jolly stupid" is not at all common.

Comment: Stereotype English is fine, actual British is fine. I mean a manner from England, not Scottish, nor Welsh, but I don't really believe that my pointing at a specific dialect from England would change anything in your answer :D (I won't mind if you prove me wrong)

Comment: Is this for a fiction that you are writing, or do you actually intend to use this yourself when talking to people?

Comment: "bloody" perhaps.

Comment: *A blithering idiot!*

Comment: @JamesK I'm going to use it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The intensifier *bloody* comes to mind, as described by [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/bloody):

> In British slang, *bloody* means something like “very.” That's *bloody* brilliant!

While this sense of the word is understood in American English, it’s very rarely used, except maybe in imitating British English. Some [other dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody) use it, but it’s still seen as British.

It used to be offensive enough to be frequently censored, though now the word is acceptable enough to be included in children’s literature.

Comment: "Flipping" might express a similar sentiment without running the risk of offending.

Answer (score 1):

With understatement, which is quintessentially British:

- This is slightly stupid.
- He's a bit of an idiot.
- He is not my favourite person.
- That film was rather good.

For more background, please see [English understatement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_understatement).